# How to convert Jquery drag and drop functions to angular directive

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

I am working on project like floor plan. The project is working 100% with JQuery but know i wanted to integrate with angularjs, for that i need to convert jquery functions to angularjs directive.

below i have posted my jquery code please can anyone help me to convert.

Thanks in advance...

.JS

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
        //Counter
        counter = 0;
        //Make element draggable
        $(".drag").draggable({
            helper:'clone',
            containment: 'frame',

            //When first dragged
            stop:function(ev, ui) {
                var pos=$(ui.helper).offset();
                objName = "#clonediv"+counter
                $(objName).css({"left":pos.left,"top":pos.top});
                $(objName).removeClass("drag");


                //When an existiung object is dragged
                $(objName).draggable({
                    containment: 'parent',
                    stop:function(ev, ui) {
                        var pos=$(ui.helper).offset();
                        console.log($(this).attr("id"));
                        console.log(pos.left)
                        console.log(pos.top)
                    }
                });
            }
        });
        //Make element droppable
        $("#frame").droppable({
            drop: function(ev, ui) {
                if (ui.helper.attr('id').search(/drag[0-9]/) != -1){
                    counter++;
                    var element=$(ui.draggable).clone();
                    element.addClass("tempclass");
                    $(this).append(element);
                    $(".tempclass").attr("id","clonediv"+counter);
                    $("#clonediv"+counter).removeClass("tempclass");

                    //Get the dynamically item id
                    draggedNumber = ui.helper.attr('id').search(/drag([0-9])/)
                    itemDragged = "dragged" + RegExp.$1
                    console.log(itemDragged)

                    $("#clonediv"+counter).addClass(itemDragged);
                }
            }
        });
    });
function readURL(event){
         var getImagePath = URL.createObjectURL(event.target.files[0]);
         $('#frame').css('background-image', 'url(' + getImagePath + ')');
        }
```

```css
.CSS
body {
   text-align: center;
   z-index: 1;
}
#wrapper {
   text-align: left;
   width: 720px;
   margin-left: auto;
   margin-right: auto;
}

#options{
    width: 700px;
    height: 90px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

#frame{
    margin-top: 25px;
    width: 700px;
    height: 550px;
    background-image: url('');
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    border: 1px solid black;
    margin-left: 0px;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 10;
}

#tbldevs{
 border:1px solid black;
 width:80%;
 margin-left:50px;
 margin-top:10px;
}

#tbldevs th{
 text-align:center;
 height:50px;
 width:50px;
}

#tbldevs td{
 height:50px;
}


#drag1 {
    margin-left: 15px;
    margin-top: 15px;
    /* background-image: url("../images/cf_32x32.png"); */
    width: 32px;
    height: 32px;
    border: 2px solid black;
    border-radius: 50%;
    float: left;
    z-index: 25;
}

#drag2 {
margin-left: 79px;
    margin-top: 15px;
    /* background-image: url("../images/cf_32x32.png"); */
    width: 60px;
    height: 32px;
    border: 2px solid black;
    z-index: 25;
}


.ui-draggable-helperMoving {
 border: 1px dotted #000;
 padding: 6px;
 background: #fff;
 font-size: 1.2em;
 width:100px;
 height:100px;
}

.ui-draggable-helperStoped {
 border: 1px solid #000;
 width:5px;
 height:5px;
}



/* classes for dragged stuff */
.dragged1 {
 position: fixed;
 /* background-image: url("../images/cf_32x32.png"); */
 width: 32px;
 height: 32px;
 border: 2px solid black;
 border-radius: 50%;
}

.dragged2 {
 position: fixed;
 /* background-image: url("../images/cf_32x32.png"); */
 width: 60px;
 height: 32px;
 border: 2px solid black;
}

/*.dragged3 {
 position:absolute; 
 background-image: url("../images/fla_32x32.png");
 width:32px;
 height:32px;
}

.dragged4 {
 position:absolute; 
 background-image: url("../images/flex_32x32.png");
 width:32px;
 height:32px;
}

.dragged5 {
 position:absolute; 
 background-image: url("../images/pdf_32x32.png");
 width:32px;
 height:32px;
}

.dragged6 {
 position:absolute; 
 background-image: url("../images/ps_32x32.png");
 width:32px;
 height:32px;
}


#element{
 border:1px solid red
}*/
```

```html
HTML

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en" xml:lang="en">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="content-script-type" content="text/javascript" />
    <meta http-equiv="content-style-type" content="text/css" />

    <title>Where have I been? - Demo</title>
    <meta name="description" content="Where have I been?" />

    <script src="http://www.google.com/jsapi" type="text/javascript"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
     google.load("jquery", "1.4.2");
  google.load("jqueryui", "1.7.2");
 </script>

 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheets/style.css" media="all" />

 <script src="js/script.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<input type='file' id='getval' name="background-image" onchange="readURL(event)" /><br/><br/>
<div id="wrapper">
 <div id="options">
  <div id="drag1" class="drag"></div> <!-- end of drag1 -->
  <div id="drag2" class="drag"></div> <!-- end of drag2 -->
  
 </div><!-- end of options -->
 <div id="frame">
 </div><!-- end of frame -->
</div><!-- end of wrapper -->
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: https://github.com/marceljuenemann/angular-drag-and-drop-lists          this  may help you

Comment: i Studied those things, but i couldn't convert above jQuery functions to Angular Directives, becouse above code is 100% working, but in jquery